# How can I check the user inputs the correct sequence of characters in a string

Tags: c++

I need the user to input a reference with this exact model : ####.###
There must be exactly 8 characters, the fifth being a full stop.

for the moment I put this code i a while statement in check the length of the string and if the fifth character is a full stop.

How can I check that the other characters are numbers ? Keeping in mind that I would need the user to input the reference in a single step.

```
bool wrongRef{true};
std::string ref;
while (wrongRef)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the reference (####.###) : ";
    std::cin >> ref;
    if (ref[4] == '.' && ref.length() == 8 )
    {
        wrongRef = false;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Wrong input. Reference should be '####.###'\n";
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `isdigit()` from `cctype`?

Comment: You should check `ref.length() == 8` before `ref[4] == '.'` to avoid out-of-bounds read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for [`std::regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). You can use it like this:

```
std::regex r{R"(^\d{4}\.\d{3}$)"};
std::cout << "Enter the reference (####.###) : ";
std::cin >> ref;
if (std::regex_match(ref, r))
 // ...
else 
  std::cout << "Wrong input. Reference should be '####.###'\n";
```

The regex works as follows:

`^` match the beginning of the string

`\d{4}` match 4 digits

`\.` match a full stop

`\d{3}` match another 3 digits

`$` match the end of the string

Comment: There should be 3 digits, not 4, after the full stop.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible options available. One easiest option would be - You may just count the digits and it should be equal to `original_string.length()-1`

Counting digit can be done like below :

```
int count_digits(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                         [](unsigned char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }
                        );
}
```

Now you can plugin this to your program as below :

```
if (ref[4] == '.' && 
    ref.length() == 8  && 
   (ref.length() -1) == count_digits(ref))
{
     //correct input
}
else
{
    //incorrect input 
}
```